# Kalman filter) Observation matrix of measurement equation and what is a good signal?

Tags: kalman-filter

I am trying to use a Kalman filter, but my data are somewhat deviating from the assumptions.

1. The noises in my measurement equation are not normally distributed. First of all, they are not zero-mean. Secondly, although the second-moment seems okay but there are some outliers. How do I address this? I understand that data often fails to meet assumptions in practice, but I would like to make the noises at least zero-mean. What can I do to remedy this?
   Can I just subtract non-zero mean from noises? Non-zero mean implies there is a bias in noise dataset so can I just substract the mean value (let's say, 0.8), and compute variance?
2. What is the optimal measurement equation, and how can I determine it?
3. Additionally, I am curious about observation matrix. Suppose a 1-D measurement equation.

$$ S_{t}=hx_{t}+\varepsilon_{t} $$

$S_{t}$ is a signal and I say that $ \varepsilon_{t} \sim N(0, R)$, and $h<0$. In this case, the value of Kalman gain $P_{t|t-1}H^{\top}(HP_{t|t-1}H^{\top}+R)^{-1}<0$. However, I haven't seen a negative Kalman gain. I am wondering if I can't use a signal having a negative relationship with a state variable.

4. The values of Kalman gains are pretty low. They range from 0 to 0.1. It implies that the information in the signal plays little role in estimating a state variable. Does it mean that the signal is useless (not good enough)? Because the signal doesn't have enough information to estimate the state variable?